# What is the use of writing App with class name?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to know what is the use of writing App with HWW, It can even run without writing App with this.
Python File => main.py

```
from kivy.app import App

class HWWApp(App):
    pass

HWWApp().run()
```

Kivy File => hww.kv

```
Label:
    text:"Hello World"
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [document](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#how-to-load-kv) it is not necessary 'cause it will truncate that (if present) at the end.